# How do I send html in a mail so that I can receive the answer back in my database?

Tags: php, email

I already have the poll that I want answered in html. What I want know is how to send a form to users so that they can answer a quick survey directly in their mail. I want to be able to save the data that I get back from them in my server (containing my database) according to the person that answered the poll. Since the poll would be answered in the mail how do I send the data back to my database.

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Quick Poll';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select name="Color">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: me <myMail@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myMailArchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: myMailCheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Send a link to the poll online.

Comment: I can't do it directly like this?

Comment: What @developerwjk suggest _does_ make sense, even if that is not what you hoped for. Always keep in mind that most people block html emails these days for security reasons (which actually does make sense). So if you rely solely on the html message you will not reach all recipients. Yes, I know ist is en vogue to use html in emails. But that does not mean it makes sense or is safe. Instead you should leave the choice to the recipients if they want to look at your survey or not. Do not make that decision for them.

Comment: If you do want to try it your way, the big thing is in `<form action="#" method="post">` for the action you need your full url `action='http://example.com/poll.php'` or whatever it is. And obviously you can't include PHP in an HTML email like you are trying.

Comment: Ok, I send a link to the poll, but then how do I know who is answering the poll? that I why I want to send it to their mails to get their email address back with the answered poll to store in the database

Comment: It won't magically give you their email address anyway. I'd suggest generating a random token representing the email you sent, and then add that as a param to the link `poll.php?token=fDsfEWf4BfsEfsdfWEfeFf`...rather than sending their email address itself all over the web.

Comment: you have syntax errors in your code right now, notice the syntax highlighting? It's talking to you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and this will never happen `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` again http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I was told by @developerwjk  php will not run in mail.

Comment: @learningbyexample PHP runs on the server. It doesn't matter whether the client is mail or a browser, it doesn't run there.